# jQuery Plugin - Calling a public method from within plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having difficulty with calling a public method from within my plugin itself. I'm not sure what the issue is. What am I doing wrong?

```
(function($) {

    var MyPlugin = function(){

        /* PUBLIC */
        this.publicFunction = function() {
            // Do public things
        };

        /* PRIVATE */
        var privateFunction = function() {
            // Do private things

            // Call this one public function
            publicFunction(); // WANT THIS but doesn't work
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        var myPlugin = new MyPlugin(options);

        // Binding click to public function
        $("a").bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            myPlugin.publicFunction($(this)); // AND WANT THIS but does
        });

        return myPlugin;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to be able to reference the `this` object of MyPlugin from within the function itself without losing scope. To do so assign it to a variable (name doesn't matter, typical convention is `self`)

```
var MyPlugin = function(){
    var self = this;
    ...
    var privatefunction = function () {
        self.publicFunction();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your MyPlugin function cache a reference to the MyPlugin instance:

```
var self = this;
```

then inside privateFunction call publicFunction as a member of self:

```
self.publicFunction();
```

The problem is that you've defined publicFunction as a member of the MyPlugin instance, not as a global (which is good), but you're calling it from a different scope and since publicFunction isn't global you need to tell javascript where to find it.  You can't use `this` because within the context of where you're calling it, `this` won't point to the MyPlugin instance

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

    var MyPlugin = function(options){

        /* PRIVATE - one copy for each instance */
        var options = $.extend({},options),
            privateFunction = function() {
                // Do private things
                // ...
                // Call this one public function
                this.publicFunction();
            };
    };

    // Shared by all MyPlugin instances;
    MyPlugin.prototype.publicFunction = function($element) {
            // Do public things
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        var myPlugin = new MyPlugin(options);

        // Binding click to public function
        $("a").bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            myPlugin.publicFunction($(this));
        });

        return myPlugin;
    };
})(jQuery);
```